# Connecting to a SignalR server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr

On the server I create a Hub

```
public class SGHub : Hub
{
    public static List<string> Users = new List<string>();

    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        Console.WriteLine(SGHub.Users.Count);
    }
}
```

On the client I connect to the Hub

```
void Start()
{
    hubConnection = new HubConnection(serverURL);
    hubConnection.Error += HubConnectionError;
    iHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateProxy("SGHub");
    Subscription subscription = iHubProxy.Subscribe("broadcastMessage");
    hubConnection.Start();
}
```

If the server is not running, and the client tries to connect to the Hub, the application hangs, how to avoid this?

Comment: How long does the client "hang"? I'm using SignalR as well and I have the clientside connection try in a Thread to avoid this. If you want me to, I can post my code. Never had problems with frozen apps.

Comment: I run the client and try to connect to the hub, which is not running.
The client after doing `hubConnection.Start();` after 5-10 seconds does not respond and Windows offers to close the application.
If it is not difficult, give an example in the code please.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to start flow with an http request to `serverURL`

and only if server returns **Ok**, you start signalr connection flow.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to put you clientside connection code in a thread. That's how I did it. Every time you have a long running task (like waiting for a timeout in your case) and you do this in the UI thread the app will freeze.

Comment: Client is in Unity 3D, I do not know or there it is possible to create an additional thread in it.

Comment: The backend is in C#, isn't it? At least the code you showed is C#

Comment: Yes, backend is in C#